# SQL Difference between MAX (from this week) and MAX (from last week)

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

In a Table I have the Mileage per Day.
Now I want a Query that give me the Miles per week.
So I thought I take the MAX value from this week and the MAX value from last week and the difference is my answer.
But how can I do this in a Query?

My Table looks like:

```
Date         Object        Value
2020-01-03   Mileage       12500
2020-01-06   Mileage       12850
2020-01-07   Mileage       13020
2020-01-10   Mileage       13200
2020-01-14   Mileage       13660
2020-01-16   Mileage       13700
```

My Query looks like:

```
SELECT dbo.Getyearweek([Date]) as ThisWeek
       ,Object
       ,MAX([Value]) as ThisWeekMax
       ,(SELECT MAX([Value])
                FROM [MyTable]
                WHERE dbo.Getyearweek(dateadd(day, -7, [Date])) ) as LastWeekMax
       ,MAX([ThisWeekMax]) - MAX([LastWeekMax]) as Difference
FROM [MyTable]
WHERE [Date] > dateadd(year, -1, GetDate())
GROUP BY dbo.Getyearweek([Date]), Object
```

Getyearweek() is a Function and gives as result the Year and Weeknumber of the given Date.
For Date 2020-01-03: 2020_01
For Date 2020-01-07: 2020_02
etc.

I expect a Result like this:

```
ThisWeek        Object       ThisWeekMax     LastWeekMax       Difference
2020_02         Mileage      13200           12500             700
2020_03         Mileage      13700           13200             500
```

Comment: You can use conditional aggregation to get the sums for your two weeks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following code will help you. I have used DATEPART to get the Week number.

```
select *,case when previousweekmax<>0 then thisweekmax-previousweekmax else 0 end as DIFF 
from
(
select week,object,val as thisweekmax,
case when week >1 then (select max(value) from test where DATEPART ( ww , date )=week-1) 
else 0 end as previousweekmax
from
(
select distinct DATEPART ( ww , date )as week,object,max(value) as val from test
group by DATEPART ( ww , date ),object
)tmp
)t
```

Output

```
week object thisweekmax previousweekmax DIFF
1   Mileage  12500           0           0
2   Mileage  13200          12500       700
3   Mileage  13700          13200       500
```

Comment: Thnx Naveen for your code.
This helped me for my Mileage per week.

Answer (score 0):

Use `lag()`:

```
SELECT dbo.Getyearweek([Date]) as ThisWeek, Object
       MAX([Value]) as ThisWeekMax,
       (value - 
        LAG(MAX([Value]) OVER (PARTITION BY Object ORDER BY dbo.Getyearweek([Date])) as prev_week_value
       ) as Difference
FROM [MyTable]
WHERE [Date] > dateadd(year, -1, GetDate())
GROUP BY dbo.Getyearweek([Date]), Object
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you have a unique identifier in this table, because you would need that to join.

```
 SELECT ID, dbo.Getyearweek(x.[Date]) as ThisWeek
           ,x.Object
           ,MAX([x.Value]) as ThisWeekMax
           ,y.LastWeekMax
           ,x.ThisWeekMax - y.LastWeekMax As Difference
           From (Select ID, Max([Value]) as LastWeekMax From [myTable]
                 Where dbo.Getyearweek(dateadd(day, -7, [Date])) )
                 Group By myTable.ID) As y Inner Join myTable as x 
                 On x.ID = y.ID
          WHERE [Date] > dateadd(year, -1, GetDate())
```